# How to disable the recommended comments section in Disqus?

Tags: jekyll, disqus, jekyll-extensions, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm new to Disqus.

I met a problem that I always see some recommended comments section below my Disqus section on Jekyll blog.
[image]

Could any one tell me how to disable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

> Discovery is a recommendation engine that helps drive traffic to pages
>   within your site.

To stop showing recommended links within your site, go to your Disqus Admin, click Settings > General and then uncheck "Discovery".

[image]